# Est-il possible qu'un pays soit anglophone sans être anglo-saxon ?

Tags: étymologie, histoire

D'après le site [educaling](https://educalingo.com/fr/dic-fr/anglophone):

> Le monde anglo-saxon est l'ensemble de pays dont l'organisation socio-économique et la culture ont été fortement influencés par la colonisation britannique et dont l'anglais est la langue principale.

Sachant que dire qu'une personne est anglophone signifie qu'elle parle anglais, cela d'après le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/anglophone/3524), je me pose la question suivante:

*Est-il possible qu'un pays soit considéré comme anglophone sans être anglo-saxon ?*

Answer (score 3):

L'article cite mot pour mot et fait directement référence à [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monde_anglo-saxon) qui indique clairement que la définition de ce terme est à géométrie variable.

Les seuls pays que tout le monde s'accorde à inclure sont le Royaume-Uni, les États-Unis, l'Australie, la Nouvelle-Zélande et le Canada<sup>1</sup> que l'on retrouve dans les [Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) (groupe des cinq).

On peut ensuite inclure des pays moins proches, mais où l'héritage de l'Empire colonial britannique est encore sensible. Dans ce cas, anglo-saxon (ou anglophone) ne fait plus référence aux régions d'origine des ancêtres d'une partie importante de la population mais à des systèmes politiques, juridiques, d'éducation, etc.

Parler de « race » n'a pas de sens ici (ou ailleurs), tout comme on ne parle pas de « race » du système de mesure anglo-saxon.

<sub>1</sub> <sub>L'inclusion des francophones canadiens est bien sûr discutée...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Oui, bien sûr ; le Nigéria n'est pas un pays dont la race soit anglo-saxonne mais la  langue officielle est l'anglais.

Il n'y a qu'à regarder la [carte de la francophonie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francophonie) dans le monde pour s'apercevoir que sont des francophones de nombreuses ethnies qui ne sont pas de race « européenne » (donc pas « française »). Il en va de même pour les anglophones.

Le monde anglo-saxon est aussi appelé l'anglophonie ; chercher « anglophonie » dans la Wikipédia ouvre l'article « monde anglo-saxon ».

Comment: En France, le mot race est aujourd'hui réservé aux animaux. Son utilisation pour des populations humaines est ici un anglicisme.

Comment: @jlliagre La France fera ce qu'elle veut avec le mot « race » et moi aussi !

Comment: On écrit aussi Nigeria, selon wiki.

Comment: @cl-r Pour parler exactement ils sont ibériens, Celtes,  Jutes, Angles, Saxons, Frisons, Danois, Norvégiens, Normands (encore des vikings), certainement des races de l'Europe; Ils sont comme les français, une panacée de race européennes, et un produit de races c'est encore une race; évidemment ces produits de races sont des races multi-facette, moins homogènes. Je suis très sérieux, au contraire.

Comment: Des Ibériens ? On ne rencontre quasiment plus ce mot depuis le XIXe siècle. Un "francophone natif" dira *des ibères* et évitera de confondre un *panachage* (mélange) et *une panacée* (médicament qui guérit tout).

Comment: @jlliagre Il y a erreur : « ibères » en français, « Hiberians » en anglais ; l'histoire, je l'ai seulement entrevue en anglais, encore moins lue en français, d'où le mélange. C'est exact, « panacée » vient tout droit de l'anglais et le sens anglais ne correspond pas (vocabulaire anglais mal assimilé au départ) ; c'est bien fondamentalement « mélange » qu'il faut et qu'il était dans mon intention d'écrire. Merci beaucoup de ces remarques utiles.

Comment: Ah, je me demandais aussi pourquoi tu avais inclus les Ibères dans cette liste. Si tu veux traduire *Hibernians*, c'est le rare *Hiberniens* (Irlandais) et pas *Ibères* (Espagnols/Portugais) qu'il faut retenir.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, il s'agit bien des « hiberians », peuple originaire de la péninsule ibérique, qui ont été supplantés par les Celtes et qui de toute façon n'ont pas eu une grande influence ; certaines approches à l'histoire anglaise n'en font pas état.

Comment: *Hibernians* est le nom donné aux peuples d'Irlande par les romains dont la racine provient du mot qui a donné *Eire* ou *Érin* in français, et altéré par la proximité avec *hibernus* (hiver). Les Ibères (*Iberians*) est le nom donné à des peuples de la péninsule ibérique par les grecs. Il n'y a pas de rapport entre les deux, sauf peut-être une étymologie indo-européenne commune (PiHwerjoHn 
 - *piouèryon*, « fertile »).

Comment: @jlliagre Non, cela date d'avant la période romaine, laquelle suit la période Celte ; je me souviens maintenant d'avoir lu le mot dans « A Shortened History  of England » by Georges Macaulay Trevelyan ; malheureusement je n'ai plus accès à ce livre. Des artéfacts que l'on retrouve dans la péninsule ibériques ont été trouvés aussi en Grande Bretagne, ce qui serait la preuve de l'existence d'une branches des peuples ibère en Angleterre avant la période celtique, c'est à dire après la période préhistorique (Stonehenge).